# Change table row color on hover (jQuery or CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My problems is that I already got some 'highlighted' (meaning that they've got their own background color to highlight them) cells in my table that won't change their background color when I use code to change color of entire row when mouse is hoovering over them.

Hoovering over a row only changes background color of cells that aren't highlighted.

How do I fix this so entire row changes background color?

I've got this HTML table:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#infotable tr').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
  });
});
```

```css
#infotable td { 
  padding:0.7em;
  border:#969696 1px solid;
}
.highlight {
  background:#DAFFD6;
}
.hover {
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="infotable">
    <tr>
      <td>Row #1</td>
      <td>889 kg</td>
      <td class="highlight">151 kg</td>
      <td>192 kg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row #2</td>
      <td>784 kg</td>
      <td>15 kg</td>
      <td class="highlight">64 kg</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why not #infotable tr:hover { background: #color }

Comment: @RemySheppard it's just for the test but thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this in CSS alone. You just need to make the `:hover` rule more specific than the `td.highlight`. Try this:

```
#infotable tr:hover td,
#infotable tr:hover td.highlight
{
    background:yellow;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hozxftav/)

Comment: better than my fiddle anyway :P

Comment: This is the **best** way to do it. Don't forget to mention that some IE versions need a specific `behavior` file so it works on those versions.

Answer (score 1):

Add class hover to all `td` insted of `tr` by changing javascript only.

```
  $('#infotable tr').hover(function()
  {
    $(this).find('td').addClass('hover');
  }, function()
  {
    $(this).find('td').removeClass('hover');
  });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/a721wjwx/)

Answer (score 1):

Just inherit the style from hover check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pv317knh/4/)

```
.hover, .hover .highlight
{
    background:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in css

```
#infotable tr td:hover
{
    background:yellow;
}
```